# How to get the url part in c#?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a string like below.

```
string filePath = @"http://s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd/text.txt" or @"http://s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd/wer/we/wed/text.txt" or @"http://s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd/wer/we/wed/sa/ser/text.txt"
```

I need to get the output as `@"http://s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd"`

I have tried substring.IndxcOf method and i got isd or std alone.

Please help on this.

Answer (score 2):

**Original Response:**

Converting the string to a `Uri` object, you can do the following:

```
//filePath = @"http://s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd/text.txt"

Uri uri = new Uri(filePath);
string output = uri.AbsoluteUri.Remove(uri.AbsoluteUri.Length - uri.Segments.Last().Length - 1); // -1 removes the '/' character at the end

// output = "http://s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd"
```

*Note: the `Last()` function is from the `System.Linq` library. If you are not using this library, you can still obtain the last segment by replacing `uri.Segments.Last().Length` with `uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length - 1].Length`.

**Updated Response** based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923439/how-to-get-the-url-part-in-c/36923604#comment61409039_36923604):

```
//filePath = @"http://s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd/ser/wer/text.txt"

Uri uri = new Uri(filePath);
string output = uri.AbsoluteUri.Remove(uri.AbsoluteUri.Length - uri.Segments.[uri.Segments.Length - 3].Length - 1); 

// uri.Segments.Length - 3 removes the last 3 unrequired "segments"
// -1 removes the '/' character at the end

// output = "http://s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd"
```

**Updated Response** based on the last revision:

```
//filePath = @"http://s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd/wer/we/wed/sa/ser/text.txt"

Uri uri = new Uri(filePath);
string output = uri.AbsoluteUri.Remove(uri.AbsoluteUri.Length - uri.Segments.[uri.Segments.Length - 6].Length - 1); 

// uri.Segments.Length - 6 removes the last 6 unrequired "segments"
// -1 removes the '/' character at the end

// output = "http://s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd"
```

---

If those three strings are possible, then you can do a conditional statement to ascertain which string to manipulate.

```
if (/* string 1 */)
   // see original response
else if (/* string 2 */)
   // see first updated response
else if (/* string 3 */)
   // see second updated response
```

Comment: if suppose if i have a path like string filePath = @"s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd/ser/wer/text.txt";; how i can proceed to get the same output?

Comment: @user2505309 See my updated response. I kept the `http://` in to maintain the integrity of my answer. Do you require not having `http://`?

Comment: @user2505309 I have answered for each of your three strings. Please view that.

Comment: please check now. all the strings are possible in my case. whatever may be string. but i need to get the output same as i mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

```
string filePath = @"http://s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd/text.txt";
int index = filePath.LastIndexOf('/');
string url = filePath.Substring(0, index);
```

Comment: if suppose if i have a path like string filePath = @"http://s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd/ser/wer/text.txt"; how i can proceed to get the same output?

Comment: do you mean, if there's no "http://" in front of the string how do you get an output with "http://" in front of it?  if (!url.StartsWith(@"http://")) { url = @"http://" + url; }

Comment: you are wrong. i need to get ouput like "http://s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd"  if the string is "http://s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd/ser/wer/text.txt";

Comment: I think the question is a little unclear as to how you want the uri segments to be divided.  If you are receiving /abc/std/isd/ser/wer (or some other combination), how are you deciding which way they should be divided?  Also, given that it's not as simple as removing the last segment, @mastermind_ed's solution will be more flexible

Answer (score 0):

How about a regex

```
var url = "http://s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd/text.txt";
// or     "http://s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd/wer/we/wed/text.txt"
// or     "http://s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd/wer/we/wed/sa/ser/text.txt"
// or     "s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd/ser/wer/text.txt"

var match = Regex.Match(url, @"^(?:http:\/\/)?(.*isd)(?=\/)");
Console.WriteLine("http://" + match.Groups[1]);

// output: http://s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd
```

Comment: The output will be the same regardless of it already containing the `http://` scheme, or which subdirectory you are in.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure on the context but I always try and keep the file name and path separate for later code modification.

```
string filePath = @"http://s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd";
string filename = "text.txt";
```

You should always be able to get your path with a Path.GetDirectoryName.  If you need other file names it makes the code much cleaner.

Comment: if suppose if i have a path like string filePath = @"s.ion.com/abc/Std/isd/ser/wer/text.txt";; how i can proceed to get the same output?